# how to secure an application by environment in symfony?

Tags: symfony1, config, security

i made a

*apps/frontend/config/security.yml*

```
dev:
 default:
  is_secure: false

prod:
 default:
  is_secure: true
```

but it is not working, am i missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As steve says, is_secure can't be configured on a per environment basis.

My guess is that you are trying to password protect your entire dev environment? I'd suggest that you use .htaccess/.htpasswd protection or equivalent to protect a site in this way.

If you can't or for whatever reason want to do it in symfony, you could make symfony accept configuration in this way by creating a custom sfSecurityConfigHandler.class.php

Config handlers have a method in them called getConfiguration - this is in charge of getting the values set in the various yml files and creating an array of the final values after all over-rides etc have been applied.

sfSecurityConfigHander.class.php has a getConfiguration like this:

```
static public function getConfiguration(array $configFiles)
{
  $config = self::flattenConfiguration(self::parseYamls($configFiles));

  // change all of the keys to lowercase
  $config = array_change_key_case($config);

  return $config;
}
```

whilst a configuration that depends on environment, such as sfDatabaseConfigHandler.class.php has one like this:

```
static public function getConfiguration(array $configFiles)
{
  $config = self::replaceConstants(self::flattenConfigurationWithEnvironment(self::parseYamls($configFiles)));

  foreach ($config as $name => $dbConfig)
  {
    if (isset($dbConfig['file']))
    {
      $config[$name]['file'] = self::replacePath($dbConfig['file']);
    }
  }

  return $config;
}
```

The key difference here is the use of self::flattenConfigurationWithEnvironment over self::flattenConfiguration. I think if you extend sfSecurityConfigHandler with:

```
class mySecurityConfigHandler extends sfSecurityConfigHandler {
    static public function getConfiguration(array $configFiles)
    {
      $config = self::flattenConfigurationWithEnvironment(self::parseYamls($configFiles));

      // change all of the keys to lowercase
      $config = array_change_key_case($config);

      return $config;
    }
}
```

and then create a config_handlers.yml file in your config telling symfony to use this class:

```
modules/*/config/security.yml:
  class:    sfSecurityConfigHandler
  file:     %sf_lib_dir%/path/to/mySecurityConfigHandler
```

You should then be able to use the yml as per the question to configure security per environment.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? I think you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the `is_secure` property.

Generally it is used to declare which modules/actions of an application should require authentication (from a plugin such as [sfGuard](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin)) rather than to protect an entire environment.

Comment: i want to disable security for testing purpose without modifying the configuration by hand, it's more convenient for me.
And yes, some of my module is securised, i just want to test it without security in the dev environment.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the only way to do this would be to set the dev environment to `is_secure: false` in each secured module.

Comment: same, environment specific configuration isn't working in module.

Comment: `all: is_secure: true dev: is_secure: false`
Doesn't work? Sorry; I'm stumped!

Comment: @belaz, note that the configuration cascade overrides always at the lower level, so if you set your frontend security to false but have modules that have their own config/security/yml where security is set to true, those modules will remain secure.